# HQL-query with discriminator column cannot query by type of subclass

Tags: hql, hibernate3, jpa-1.0

I'm using JPA1.0 and Hibernate 3.3. (There is currently no option to upgrade).

I want to query a generic table `GenericOrderType` with `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` strategy and `@Discriminatorcolumn(name="ORDER_TYPE")`.

Running the following query WITHOUT `AND type(o) = 'SubOrderType'` works.

```
select OBJECT(o) from GenericOrderType o where o.id = :orderid AND type(o) = 'MiniOrderType'
```

If I append `AND type(o) = 'MiniOrderType'` I get a persistence exception.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [java.lang.String] expected instance/subclass of [com.doe.GenericOrderType]
```

I did not find the correct syntax to query by type (subclass) with Hibernate 3.3 and JPA 1.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/

Any hints appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have only the two order types: Mini and Sub? In other words, does it work with any other implementations of GenericOrderType?

Comment: I gave in finding a solution and simply used `...from MiniOrderType` instead of `...AND type(o) = 'MiniOrderType'`. That is okay, too. At least for JPA1.0